# How to pass hidden parameter to controller in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, parameter-passing

I'd like to pass the parameter `recipient` to controller. I can show it in my view like this:

```
@recipient.username
```

How can I pass this value to `params[:message][:recipient]`? Note that I do not have a model called "Message".

controllers/messages_controller.rb

```
def deliver
  recipient = User.find_by_username(params[:recipient])
  subject = params[:subject]
  body = params[:body]

  current_user.send_message(recipient, body, subject)
  redirect_to :controller => 'messages', :action => 'received' 
  flash[:notice] = "message sent!"
end
```

views/messages/new.html.erb

```
<td><%= @recipient.username if @recipient %></td>

<%=form_for :messages, url: url_for( :controller => :messages, :action => :deliver ) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </div> 

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by assigning an attr_accessible key for your Recipient and assign it to the form.

```
form_for :message do |f|
  f.hidden_field :recipient_id, :value => @recipient.id.to_i
  f.text_field :message
  f.submit
end
```

once you pass this to your create action you are able to check params[:message][:recipient_id]

and pass this to the db.

Have fun