# find or create by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

i have added the following setter/getter methods to my model, though whenever i try and save the form i am getting an error about mass assignment. from my understanding how this should work is, that if the opponent_name cant be found it will add a entry to the database

```
def opponent_name
opponent.try(:name)
end

def opponent_name(name)
    self.opponent = Opponent.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
```

here is the error from the console log

```
    Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-26 19:07:26 +1100
Processing by EventsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h7OrLKeDL/9KmZeGZeO+QTWHtlUdOlaMqnoMGhYaDUU=", "event"=>{"datetime(3i)"=>"2", "datetime(2i)"=>"3", "datetime(1i)"=>"2013", "datetime(4i)"=>"00", "datetime(5i)"=>"00", "event"=>"1", "location_id"=>"7", "duration"=>"30", "arrival_time"=>"30", "opponent_name"=>"Test", "home_or_away"=>"Home"}, "commit"=>"Create Event"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: opponent_name):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:22:in `catch_not_found'
```

opponent model

```
class Opponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :events
  belongs_to  :team

  attr_accessible :name, :team_id

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

event model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :opponent
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :result
  has_many :availabilities, :dependent => :destroy

  def opponent_name
    opponent.try(:name)
  end

  def opponent_name(name)
    self.opponent = Opponent.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end

  attr_accessible :location_id, :user_id, :datetime, :score_for, :score_against, :event,
                  :team_id, :home_or_away, :arrival_time, :duration, :selected_players, :date, :time, :result_id

  validates :event, :location_id, :team_id, :presence => true
  validates_numericality_of :team_id, :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to =>0, :message => " needs to be set, please contact your Administrator"
  #validates_numericality_of :arrival_time, :only_integer =>true, :greater_than_or_equal_to =>0, :message => " must be greater than 0 minutes", :allow_blank => true
  validates :home_or_away, :presence => true, :if => :event == 1
  validates :score_for, :presence => true, :if => :score_against
  validates :score_against, :presence => true, :if => :score_for

  EVENT_TYPES = [['Game', 1], ['Training', 2], ['Social Event', 3]]
  HOME_OR_AWAY = [:Home, :Away]

end
```

Comment: What does the rest of your model look like? Have you whitelisted the necessary columns (including opponent_name) using attr_accessible?

Comment: `attr_accessible :location_id, :user_id, :datetime, :score_for, :score_against, :event,
                  :team_id, :home_or_away, :arrival_time, :duration, :selected_players, :date, :time, :result_id`

Comment: when i added :opponent_name i get `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: opponent_name):`

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane could you please post your Event model and also your Opponent model, to see clearer picture.

Comment: i think you have to do this attr_accessible :name

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane has the answer below to put in event model helped? :)

Comment: What is line 22 of your ApplicationController?

Comment: @Mischa `private

  def catch_not_found
    yield
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_url, :flash => { :alert => 'It looks like you\'ve requested a web page that doesn\'t actually exist.' }
  end`

Comment: The problem may be that you defined your setter like `def opponent_name(name)` while it should be `def opponent_name=(name)`. When you do this *and* `attr_accessible :opponent_name`, it may work. Not sure why it errors out on that line. Seems unrelated to the error.

Comment: @Mischa this has got me a bit closer now :)

Comment: I would give him +2 but I couldn't as it is allowing only +1 as he saw obvious what we all missed :)

Comment: Glad to hear you're closer to solving it. Good luck.

Comment: next put would be if i created a new opponent on file, how can i pass a second variable like an id when the object is created?

Comment: you can define hidden value it in your view, but that might not be a good approach. What do you want to accomplish? Also, have you solved this `attr_accessible` problem? if so , I am curious what was the solution?

Comment: solution was doing the fix mischa mentioned teamed with `attr_accessor :opponent_name
  attr_accessible :opponent_name` in my events model

Comment: Could you mark an answer with - answered if defining `attr_accessible :opponent_name` helped , so it could point to others when they visit this site with similar problem.

Comment: @Mischa if i wanted to pass an variable from the same form how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put in your **Event** model

```
attr_accessible :opponent_name
```

It should clear the error then

**Edit:**

Just updating an answer, but all credits goes to [Mischa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84631/mischa) for this edit.

> The problem may be that you defined your setter like def
>   opponent_name(name) while it should be def opponent_name=(name)

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane also try to define your methods after attr_accessible , validations, associations and other general definitions. It makes the code more readable and easier to trace the problem in the future. Just and advice.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in EventsController#create

unknown attribute: opponent_name`

Comment: and you deleted `attr_accessible :opponent_name` from Opponent model? just double checking

Comment: sure have, dont i need a column in my db called opponent_name for attar_accessiable to work/

Comment: no you don't need a column in db for attr_accessible to work. if you define it in your form, you can access it in your model as getter and setter, but that is another story. And second question - have you tried defining `def opponent_name` at the very end of your model, after all attr_accessible and other elements?

Comment: i have moved the setter/getter below, still same issue

Comment: Aleks, if i went down the option of using a hidden field, how would i pass that variable into the setter?

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane take a look at this link, it should give you an idea what I have meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347646/how-to-pass-hidden-parameter-to-controller-in-rails3

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html).

I beleive you have to add following statement in your Opponent model

```
attr_accessible :opponent_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If opponent_name is a field in your model's database table, then Rails has already defined getters and setters for that attribute. All you need to do is add 
attr_accessible :opponent_name

Answer (score 0):

Reference @Mischa

The problem may be that you defined your setter like def opponent_name(name) while it should be def opponent_name=(name). When you do this and attr_accessible :opponent_name, it may work. Not sure why it errors out on that line. Seems unrelated to the error.